# I want restore fragment or do not re-oncreate it when re-back to the fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, tabs

I use ActionBar with 3 swipe-tabs.

First-Tab : get a ListView from data of my server when onCreate() & onResume().

Second-Tab : get a ListView from data of my server when onCreate()

Third-Tab : get a some data of my server when onCreate()

Here is a question, When I swipe to Third-Tab and re-back to First-Tab, First-Tab's Fragment is going to onCreate() -> so re-downloading data from my server, and It looks uneffective...

How can I keep my fragment? Please help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use [`setOffscreenPageLimit`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit%28int%29) method:

```
mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Write this code in all the three fragments you have. This will allow your fragment to inflate
the view when its not already inflated.

```
            if (view != null) {
            ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
            parent.removeView(view);
        } else {
            //inflate your view here
        }
```